# Rules I need to keep in mind while asking question that not to be downvoted

Tags: support, down-votes

What are the rules I need to keep in mind while asking question that not to be downvoted? Because I dont want to do that mistake again.

Comment: Don't ask us to not downvote, that is our right/freedom. But you asking here shows the right attitude to not get a downvote.

Comment: I take it you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909403/running-total-using-cursor-with-negative-value)?

Comment: You could try Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Also [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry for ask that @Sergio

Comment: Rule number one: I is never typed `i`. Always `I`.

Comment: Rule number two: sentences start with capital letters. Titles too. :)

Answer (score -2):

Ask better questions.  If you ask better questions, you will not be downvoted.  If you ask poor questions, you will be downvoted. You cannot ask people not to downvote you; they will downvote or upvote based on the quality of your questions.  For more information on asking good questions, peruse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: Downvotes please explain.

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful because it's rather aggressive. Read it in the voice of another: "Ask better questions, djechlin." It doesn't provide any advice on how to improve the questions, either. Also, it doesn't answer this question in particular.

Comment: Lol, somebody who is giving advice on how not to be downvoted is being downvoted, oh the irony